# Create common ObjectMapper method for deserializing across multiple POJO classes

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I have created a simple ObjectMapper method for deserializing my map to a DTO class . See below:

```
    RequestDTO requestDTO;
    public static requestDTO deserializeRequestBody(HashMap<String,Object> requestMap) {
    try {
    requestDTO = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestMap), RequestDTO.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return requestDTO;
    }
```

In above code requestMap is converted to JSON string using `writeValueAsString` and then consumed by RequestDTO class using `readValue` .

Question : I have multiple RequestDTO classes(POJO) & I want to use the same ObjectMapper (as above) .I want that mapper resolves which POJO class to map to without me explicitly writing it for every class ex:

```
//Don't want to do this
objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestMap), RequestDTO1.class);
objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestMap), RequestDTO2.class);
objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestMap), RequestDTO3.class);
```

**I want the POJO class to be resolved basis the JSON keys read from requestMap Or if there is a better way to uniquely identify which class is to be used for mapping.**

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this and it seems working properly. For more details, you can check https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper/getTypeFactory?snippet=5ce6b2a237d9ff0004dd4adf.

```
public static <T> T deserializeObject(String json, Class<T> cls) {
    T result = null;
    JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(cls);
    try {
      result = objectMapper.readValue(json, javaType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("An error occurred during object deserialization", e);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You serialize a `Map` to a JSON object and then parse this JSON object into a Java class instance. This looks a little bit complicated.

If you want to decide which Java class to instantiated based on the keys in the map, maybe implement this logic by hand. Look into the keys of the map, decide which Java class to create an instance of, pass the map to a constructor of this class that populates the members.

JSON and Jackson are not needed.

Comment: would  require proper explanation and code for "implement this logic by hand"